# Looping through specific divs

Tags: jquery, loops, html, gallery

I'm trying to make an endless loop that goes through divs and displays an image and some description text in some other div, so basically it's a gallery.

```
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="header">gallery</div>
    <div class="gimages"></div>
    <div class="ggallery">
        <div class="gitem" id="0"><div class="imgtext"><div>text</div></div><img src="images/gallery/1.jpg" border="0" /></div>
        <div class="gitem" id="1"><div class="imgtext"><div>text</div></div><img src="images/gallery/2.jpg" border="0" /></div>
        <div class="gitem" id="2"><div class="imgtext"><div>text</div></div><img src="images/gallery/3.jpg" border="0" /></div>
        <div class="gitem" id="3"><div class="imgtext"><div>text</div></div><img src="images/gallery/4.jpg" border="0" /></div>
        <div class="gitem" id="4"><div class="imgtext"><div>text</div></div><img src="images/gallery/5.jpg" border="0" /></div>
        <div class="gitem" id="5"><div class="imgtext"><div>text</div></div><img src="images/gallery/6.jpg" border="0" /></div>
        <div class="gitem" id="6"><div class="imgtext"><div>text</div></div><img src="images/gallery/7.jpg" border="0" /></div>
        <div class="gitem" id="7"><div class="imgtext"><div>text</div></div><img src="images/gallery/8.jpg" border="0" /></div>
        <div class="gitem" id="8"><div class="imgtext"><div>text</div></div><img src="images/gallery/9.jpg" border="0" /></div>
        <div class="gitem" id="9"><div class="imgtext"><div>text</div></div><img src="images/gallery/10.jpg" border="0" /></div>
        <div class="gitem" id="10"><div class="imgtext"><div>text</div></div><img src="images/gallery/11.jpg" border="0" /></div>
        <div class="gitem" id="11"><div class="imgtext"><div>text</div></div><img src="images/gallery/12.jpg" border="0" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The div ggallery is display:none and I get the data from here to place in the div gimages.
The problem is that it will only show the last image unless I put an alert in between every iteration. Here's the script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var refreshId = setInterval( function(){
        $('.gallery .ggallery .gitem').each(function(index){
            $('.gallery .gimages').html($(this).html());
            if(index==11){
                index = 0;
            }
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var list = $('.gallery .ggallery .gitem');
   var j = 0;
   var f = function() {
       $('.gallery .gimages').html($(list[j%list.length]).html());
       j++;
   };        
   setInterval(f, 2000);
});​
```

See full fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kokoklems/nQGw9/

What I am doing is simply defining a function that change the content of you `gimages` div, and then call it every 2 sec thanks to the setInterval function. The trick to go back to beginning is the use of the `list[j%list.length]`.

Answer (score 1):

Move your timer inside of the loop - you're running your loop every 5 seconds and getting to the end rather than going to the next item and waiting 5 seconds (not tested)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.gallery .ggallery .gitem').each(function(index){
        var refreshId = setInterval( function(){
            $('.gallery .gimages').html($(this).html());
            if(index==11){
                index = 0;
            }
        }, 5000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your html, following is the code. you can change interval as well.

```
function init(){
        var itemInterval = 1000;
        var numberOfItems = $('.gitem').length;
        var currentItem = 0;
        setInterval(function () {
            $(".gimages").html($('#' + currentItem).clone());
            if (currentItem == numberOfItems - 1) {
                currentItem = 0;
            } else {
                currentItem++;
            }

        }, itemInterval);
    };

    $(function () {
        init();
    });
```